# WAN/Campus network design - Learning purposes

Tags: cisco, network, packet-tracer, wan, frame-relay

I am trying to build a WAN connecting various LAN's via frame-relay for learning purposes, i do not have that much experience with frame-relay or network design (mainly creating LAN's and connecting them through frame-relay).

This is the topology here, there are two sub interfaces on serial ports to avoid split horizon and connect to both other routers. The part I'm getting stuck on, is if my understanding is correct and i should have an edge router that connects to the ISP giving connectivity to the internet throughout the WAN or does every router connect to an ISP for connectivity on the LAN, i will be using a loopback address to simulate the ISP here:

[image]

Comment: The ISPs have eliminated frame relay switches, but most will still allow you to use frame relay as a layer-2 protocol on a serial point-to-point link between the CE and PE.

Comment: Your questions really depend on information you have not provided. For example, your number 3 depends on a lot of things. There are reasons to run BGP with your ISP, but there are also reasons not to. We need some objective information to determine if it is necessary, and Packet Tracer may not be able to handle what you want. I do not think you have thought this through enough to ask a question. A diagram of what you are trying to accomplish will go a long way to helping us understand the design.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide enough specific information to be able to help you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say where you are located, but frame-relay is practically obsolete in most places.

You should start with your carriers to see what technologies are available and cost effective for your requirements (bandwidth, availability, etc).   Then, you can design your network around that.    Most of your other design questions will follow from your choice of WAN technology.

Comment: Sorry Ron i forgot to put in that this is for learning purposes/Practices not implementation but i will keep this in mind, thank you

Comment: There is no "one way" to design a WAN network,so the answer to your three questions is "It depends."  Your Internet connectivity is just another WAN connection, so the technology can be whatever you want.  If you have a rough design of your training network,please include it in your question and we can offer you some more specific advice.